# X-editable - change source dynamically

Tags: jquery, x-editable

Hello I would like to change the source of the select element dinamically. I have this code:

```
$('.responsible').editable({
                     source: [{id_pass:56, text:"AAG"}, {id_pass:9, text:"AE"}, {id_pass:45, text:"ECH"}, {id_pass:17, text:"GM"}
, {id_pass:6, text:"JG"}, {id_pass:26, text:"JS"}],
                     select2:{
                         width:'112px',
                         tokenSeparators: [",", " "],
                         multiple:true,
                         id: function (item) {
                            return item.id_pass;
                         },
                         placeholder: "Select a user"
                     },
                      success: function(response, newValue) {                                                    
                       ///this doesn't work
                        $(this).editable('option', 'source', response.new_source);                                                     

                    }
});
```

In some cases is necesary that the deleted element no longer appear in the selection lists, that's why it change the source.
What can I do?
Thank you.